# String or binary data would be truncated Error when the data has no issues

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, daemon

I have an error on a working pop3 daemon that is supposed to pull email data from the server and insert it into multiple local database tables. But I seem to get this issue in my log every second which I believe is negatively affecting database performance and using a lot of database pools.

After seeing this message I checked the length of my column data and also implemented a code that restricts data from accessing DB if it exceeds specified length. But even after this the error still occurs. It's odd that executing this query separately in a database inserts the data. But running it in WAS causing problems. SQL Server 2015. There are no triggers to the table.

[image: TABLE CONSTRAINTS]

> [SQL Error] errorCode : 8152, sqlState : 22001, message : string or binary data would be truncated

```
INSERT INTO t_mail_rcvinfo
  (
    rcvInfoId,
    mailId,
    rcvType,
    rcvIdType,
    rcvId,
    sortNo,
    rcvName,
    device,
    regUserId,
    regDate,
    chgUserId,
    chgDate
   ) 
VALUES 
   (
    'CA2MLe38cc3c33863bb3b26bd8a36edeebc01',
    'CA2MLe38cc3be3863bb3b26bd8a360f3fa9c7',
    'TO',
    'EMAIL',
    'datpt@email.com',
    '3',
    'datpt@email.com',
    'PC',
    null,
    '2020-03-17 12:02:07.056',
    null,
    '2020-03-17 12:02:07.056'
   )
```

//Implemented Code after looking at the issue

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
MailRcvInfoVO infoVO = (MailRcvInfoVO)list1.get(i);         
  if (infoVO.getRcvId().getBytes("UTF-8").length > 200) {
    rcvToIdLength = infoVO.getRcvId().getBytes("UTF-8").length;
    isValidMail = false;
    break;
  }

  if (infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length > 200) {
    rcvToNameLength = infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length;
    isValidMail = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use sql profiler to check what queries are getting executed.

Comment: Thx but insert into t_mail_rcvinfo query posted above was the query that caused the error. All similar type of inserts causes errors.

Comment: Your issue is `rcvInfoId` field. What is `rcvInfoId` filed type? @TurtleSK

Comment: rcvInfoid and mailid are just unique UUID generated to use as primary keys. I don't think this is the issue because these generated uuid are used for all the other tables.

Comment: Have you had a look at Brent Ozar's suggestion regarding turning trace flag 460 on. It gives you more information about the offending column/value. Brent's blog post is available here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/how-to-fix-the-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/

Comment: I've looked into this and set traceon(460,-1) but it seems there is no capture, I think this is because mine is MSSQL 2015.

Comment: Given the table schema you have specified your example query does not cause a "String or binary data would be truncated" warning. Are you sure that t_mail_rcvinfo doesn't have any triggers?

Comment: Yes. I don't have triggers for any of my tables.

Comment: It seems the code rcvToNameLength = infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length; I've written seems to be running when the daemon starts for a few seconds (logged) then it goes dead... (no longer logged.) Not sure why and there's no error.

Comment: There is **NO** SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - so which one are you really using ?